# Calling a FORTRAN.dll with VBA (or VB.NET) with polymorphic parameter

Tags: excel, vba, dll, fortran, polymorphism

I am trying to call a Fortran.dll within my VBA-Code written in the Excel IDE. The code in Fortran contains a module where three derived types are defined and two of them extends the first one. The subroutine which is exported via the DLLEXPORT directive (in the file Fortran.dll) takes one derived type and a another parameter. However, the derived type parameter is intended to be polymorphic. Depending on the specified type the routine differs. For this purpose I am using the >> select type << directive.

In the following say, *UC* is the "base class" and *LC* the respective extensions. The subroutine takes a the polymorphic variable *DT* declared as a class(UC) and a variable *var* declared as double. Depending on the specified type of *DT* either the component of *LC1* is multiplied with the factor or the component of *LC2* is divided by the factor. The Fortran code looks like this:

```
module XY

Type, public   :: UC
   real(8) :: var_uc
end type UC

type, public, extends(UC)   :: LC1
   real(8) :: var_lc1
end type LC1

type, public, extends(UC)   :: LC2
   real(8) :: var_lc2
end type LC2

end module

subroutine sub_f(DT, var)
    !!DEC$ ATTRIBUTES DLLEXPORT, STDCALL, ALIAS:'sub_f' :: sub_f
    !!DEC$ ATTRIBUTES REFERENCE :: DT
    !!DEC$ ATTRIBUTES REFERENCE :: var

    Use XY

    class(UC), intent(in)  :: DT
    real(8), intent(in)    :: var

    select type(DT)
    class is(LC1)
     write(*,*) DT%var_lc1*var
    class is(LC2)
     write(*,*) DT%var_lc2/var
    end select

end subroutine sub_f
```

So far so good. But I don't know how to declare the parameter *DT* the binding-statement of the .dll in VBA. What did work is to declare the input parameter *DT* directly as the specified type, lets say LC1, and use a record-set with the same components in VBA in accordance to the definition of LC1 in Fortran. The corresponding statement in VBA reads:

```
' Recordset in VBA

Public Type LC1
    var_uc As Double
    var_lc1As Double
End Type

' Import of the dll

Public Declare PtrSafe Sub sub_f Lib "Fortran.dll" (ByRef DT LC1, ByRef var As Double)
```

But this is not what I want. What did not work is to pass a record-set with all the components that would fit to one extension explicitly. This is quite comprehensible, because the declared types in VBA and Fortran differs.

The class-method in VBA seems not be compatible, or more precisely: I didn't get it to work.

Questions:

- Is this even possible with VBA? If yes: Can you pls give me some tips and hints to get this done? :)
- If not, do this work with VB.NET or VB6?

Maybe some background: I am implementing several methods to do thermodynamic equilibrium calculations. This calculations are written in Fortran but called from VB. The major of this calculations do not depend on the used property method. The distinction is just made within a few subroutines, e.g. calculate the fugacity coefficient. The chosen property method and its parameters are stored in the derived type, and the distinction is made via the select type directive.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Thx for your reply and i apologize for my late response. I dont know exactly what do you mean i have to declare with baval instead of byref. The class i declared in VBA or a record set with the same components that would fit to one extension explicitly?

Comment: Could you add the result of **dumpbin /exports <dllname>**.  It may be just that your alias is incorrect.  Normally when you use stdcall types, the name looks something like _sub_f@12.  It is something like 4 for integers, reals, 8 for real(8), and any derived types.

Comment: You will need to pop up a visual studio cmd prompt to use dumpbin.  Alternatively, if you are not using visual studio, get https://www.dependencywalker.com/.  Load up your DLL and see what the function signature is.